# Exporting function names from C++ Dll to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a working DLL written in C++ with Visual Studio 2015. It contains many functions of the form:

```
BECALIBRARY_API  int Functions::GetVersion(char* ptrVersionString)
{
    char * Version;
    Version = "Test 123456";
    strcpy_s(ptrVersionString, strlen(Version) + 1, Version);
    return  strlen(Version);
}
```

The Delphi function to retrieve this is:

```
unit uBecaLibrary;

interface

function getVersion(Str1: pAnsichar): integer; stdCall;

implementation

function getVersion; external 'BecaLibrary.dll' index 1;
//function getVersion; external 'BecaLibrary.dll' name 'getVersion';

end.
```

This works fine except that I have to maintain the Delphi code using the index numbers of the DLL.

What do I need to do to both the C++ side and the Delphi Seattle Windows 10 side to use function names rather than indexes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dumpbin` utility to view exported names as

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe" /EXPORTS BecaLibrary.dll`

Names will probably be mangled but it should not be a problem.

If you can change DLL, you can add following inside function body to export unmangled name

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)
```

Comment: There is an algorithm for generating mangled names. IIRC they contain the number of bytes of the parameters somehow, but it has been a long time since I looked into this.

Comment: Yes - that does work. The mangled name for a simple call to getVersion becomes;
function getVersion; external 'BecaLibrary.dll' name '?GetVersion@Functions@BecaLibrary@@SAHPAD@Z';

I call Dlls that were created using Embarcadero C++ and they don't come mangled. Is there a way to stop Visual Studio from doing this?

Comment: You can add following in the function body to also export unmangled name     #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the function name on the last like this

```
var
function getVersion(Str1: pAnsichar): integer; stdCall; external 'BecaLibrary.dll' name 'GetVersion';

implementation
```

For the DLL

To export an undecorated name, you can link by using a Module Definition (.def) file that defines the undecorated name in an `EXPORTS` section. For more information, see `EXPORTS`. Another way to export an undecorated name is to use a 
   `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:alias=decorated_name")` 
 directive in the source code.

When you declare dllexport or dllimport, you must use extended attribute syntax and the __declspec keyword. 
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The names are exported but are mangled. The name for 'GetVersion' becomes:
  '?GetVersion@Functions@BecaLibrary@@SAHPAD@Z';

Comment: If this doesn't work, i think you need to export/expose functions different https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx